# How can I give a throwable potion in the Inventory of a player? [Spigot 1.9] [Bukkit Plugin]?

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

My problem is that I want to give a throwable potion to a player, but by using my code the player only gets a throwable glass bottle without any effects and textures. I posted a screenshot of that on following link: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=1bb67f-1467295693.png
(Also there are no Errors in my Serverlog.)
How can I give the player the correct potion and no glass bottles without textures? Thanks for your help.
My Code:

```
private static void setWitcherKit() {

    sword = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_SWORD);
    sword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);

    goldenapple = new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);

    healpotion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 4, (short) 16389);

    speedpotion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 2, (short) 8194);

    damagepotion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 4, (short) 16396);

    weaknesspotion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 2, (short) 16392);

    helmet = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_HELMET);

    chestplate = new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE);

    leggings = new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS);

    boots = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_BOOTS);
}
```

I think the reason for the problem is that I´m using the Spigot 1.9 not the Spigot 1.8 and something about the potions have been changed from the 1.8 to the 1.9. But I`m not sure.

Comment: Ask in English please.

Comment: Sorry I rewrited the question.

Comment: And the title, please. Otherwise people will never find your question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I will rewrite it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the 1.9 potions are bugged.
A sollution to that is to do it manually, [as presented](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/1-9-potion-class-fix.128274/#post-1363362) by forseth11 from spigot forums.

What you can do is use [the class forseth provided](https://gist.github.com/forseth11/31b914badd376dbd38e2), as it's a quick way to get the potions you want

Although the issue is [marked as solved by Spigot's team](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jira/browse/SPIGOT-1673), I believe that the old API will not be functional again, as stated by md_5 (spigot dev)

Answer (score 0):

I used at my plugin the normal item-stack create

```
ItemStack potion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION)
```

as you did and set afterwards the data of it with

```
potion.setData(byte data);
```

it worked for me at that time. I wouldn't bother using a derpecated method at that time because bukkit/spigot is not providing a good replacement at the moment.
But if you want, you could try to set the addition `MaterialData` as needed in the new `.setData(MaterialData data)` method.